# WPF Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn to SelectedItem of a ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

I am building an app in `WPF` (MVVM).
The user is to make a selection in a `ComboBox`, and the choice is supposed to filter the results available in a `DataGridComboBoxColumn` (DGCBC) in a `DataGrid`.

But I am at a loss at how to bind the `ComboBox` `SelectedItem` to the DGCBC. I did manage to have the `ComboBox` filter the results of a second `ComboBox`, but that logic does not seem to transfer well to the DGCBC.

What I have tried:

My `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox
    DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName1"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Collection1}"
    Loaded="{s:Action NameOfMethodToPopulateComboBox}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding PropertyHolder, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The `PropertyHolder` is ran when an item is selected in the `ComboBox`, and if it's not null, it runs the method that adds to the `ObservableCollection` which is bound to the DGCBC. It looks like this:

```
private ClassName _currentSelectedItem;
public ClassName CurrentSelectedItem {
    get { return this,._selectedItem; }
    set { SetAndNotify(ref this._selectedItem, value);
        if (value != null) {
           FillDataGridComboBoxColumn();
        }
    }
}
```

The method, `FillDataGridComboBoxColumn()` looks like this (abbreviated):

```
DataSet ds = new();
    // Code to run stored procedure
    // CurrentSelectedItem is given as parameter value

DataTable dt = new();
dt = ds.Tables[0];

MyObservableCollection.Clear();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr = dt.Rows[i];
    HolderClass holderClass = new(); // this is the class that is bound to the observablecollection
    holderClass.PropertyName = dr["PropertyName2"].ToString();
    MyObservableCollection.Add(holderClass);
```

This is the XAML for the `DataGrid` and the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGrid
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">

        <DataGridComboBoxColumn
            SelectedValueBinding="{Binding PropertyName2, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            SelectedValuePath="PropertyName2"
            DisplayMemberPath="PropertyName2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding MyObservableCollection}">
/>

</DataGrid>
```

When I debug, the `DataGridComboBoxColumn` is able to get the correct number of rows - but they're just empty placeholders; blanks. If I put a break-point in the code, I see that the collection is indeed loaded with the correct values, but they're just not showing.

I am guessing I am doing something wrong with the binding for the DGCBC.

Thank you.

Comment: You have no binding for `DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemSource`. And I can't really understand what should the DataGrid and The DGCBC column display? Maybe you should show more code, for example what collection gets filtered and how when the user chooses an item in the combobox?

Comment: How is `PropertyHolder` implemented and how do you actually populate the `ComboBox` in the `DataGrid`? Your example doesn't tell.

Comment: @mm8, thank you for your comment. You are right - I have updated my question.

Comment: @Steeeve, thank you for commenting! I wasn't aware that I had to have an `ItemsSource` for both the `DataGrid` and its columns (not required for `TextColumns` - why is it for a `ComboBoxColumn`? I did try to set the `ObservableCollection` as `ItemsSource` for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`, but to no avail.

Comment: A TextColumn shows a single property of a row in your datasource. A ComboBox has mpre items (specified with ItemsSource) of which one, the SelectedItem matches the property of the datarow in the datagrid. I'm still not understanding your goal here, but without an ItemSource in your DataGridComboBoxColumn you wouldn't have any items to choose from.

Comment: @Steeeve, thank you for elaborating. I am using an inner join to filter all the Property2's that belong to Property1. They belong to different tables in my database. So I use a inner join to achieve that. I want to click an item in the ComboBox (its filled with all Property1s), and underneath it is a DataGrid with a DGCBC, which is then supposed to be filled with all the Property2's that belong to that Property1. Hope I am doing an OK job explaining this.

I did make a typo in my question, which I've corrected: (Changed "PropertyName" to "PropertyName2" in the for-loop).

Comment: No, it doesn't get better. As I said, if you don't bind some collection of objects having a property named 'Property2' to the ItemSource of your DataGridComboBoxColumn, you won't get anything displayed. Also, have a look at the output window in visual studio, I'm sure you'll find binding errors there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataGridComboBoxColumn` `ItemSource` had to be set as a `Static Resource`:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyObservableCollection" Source="{Binding MyObservableCollection}"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

And then, in the XAML for the `DataGridComboBoxColumn`:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyObservableCollection}}"
    DisplayMemberPath="Property2">
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```